# Upgraded Ubuntu to 16.04, now Wordpress updates don't work

Tags: ssh, apache2, wordpress

I had my Ubuntu 15.10 system working just fine, and Wordpress updates happened over ssh. But when I upgraded Ubuntu to 16.04, the switch to php7.0 broke Wordpress updates. At first it was prompting for FTP login credentials until I installed php-ssh2 (which cautions that it's based on a git snapshot). Now when I try to upgrade a plugin, it says

```
An error occurred while updating WP to Twitter: Unable to locate WordPress Content directory (wp-content).
```

And in /var/log/apache2/error.log:

```
[Sun Jun 12 11:01:10.969931 2016] [:error] [pid 5545] [client 192.168.1.11:65278] PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(): Unable to open ssh2.sftp://Resource id #81/.maintenance on remote host in /home/blog/wordpress/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-ssh2.php on line 252, referer: http://xxxx.com/wp-admin/update-core.php?action=do-plugin-upgrade
[Sun Jun 12 11:01:10.970772 2016] [:error] [pid 5545] [client 192.168.1.11:65278] PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(ssh2.sftp://Resource id #81/.maintenance): failed to open stream: operation failed in /home/blog/wordpress/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-ssh2.php on line 252, referer: http://xxxx.com/wp-admin/update-core.php?action=do-plugin-upgrade
```

Am I missing a package, or a configuration item, or what?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same problem. This seems to be a bug in php-ssh2 (from the Ubuntu repo).

After removing php-ssh2, and installing a newer version with pecl (pecl install ssh2-1.0), the problem was solved.

I submitted a bug report:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php-ssh2/+bug/1617294

Comment: Well, that was easy. I didn't know about pecl.

Comment: @Rick After burning half a Saturday trying to figure this out, your solution solved it in under 5 minutes. Thanks for sharing this!

Comment: Alternative to pecl: you can also choose to use the package from [Yakkety](http://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety/php-ssh2). For me it didn't give compatibility issues.

Comment: Using pecl somehow did not work out for me even after installing php7.0-dev (the pecl command ended with a Segmentation Fault!). Hugos solution with getting php-ssh2 from Yakkety is much easier!

Comment: And all of a sudden the problem is back!
[Fri Jan 27 09:00:45.336663 2017] [:error] [pid 17823] [client 192.168.1.2:47812] PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(ssh2.sftp://Resource id #85/.maintenance): failed to open stream: operation failed in /home/blog/wordpress/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-ssh2.php on line 253, referer: http://blog.xcski.com/wp-admin/update-core.php?action=do-plugin-upgrade

Answer (score 1):

Installing the pecl extension didn't worked for me (Who knows why) but I found an alternative:

I just uploaded this Plugin via scp to my VPS and it solved the problem: https://wordpress.org/plugins/ssh-sftp-updater-support/

Answer (score 1):

In my case none of the above worked, however, [a patch by ralphm](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/35517) in the PHP code fixed the update-via-ssh2-problem for WordPress on both Ubuntu 14.04 and Ubuntu 16.04 for me:

```
--- a/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-ssh2.php
+++ b/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-ssh2.php
@@ -185,7 +185,7 @@
        if ( '/' === $path ) {
            $path = '/./';
        }
-       return 'ssh2.sftp://' . $this->sftp_link . '/' . ltrim( $path, '/' );
+       return 'ssh2.sftp://' . intval($this->sftp_link) . '/' . ltrim( $path, '/' );
    }

    /**
```

Do not forget to reapply this patch after updating until a final fix makes it to the WordPress release.

Comment: Thanks for this! Worked for me without having to mess with pecl

Answer (score 0):

In my case only Installing version of 1.1.2 lib helped... 
`pecl install ssh2-1.1.2`

- PHP 7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
- Apache/2.4.18